# Spring Boot - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

During post request create user request, following error is came.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.springbootrestfulwebservice.service.UserService.createUser(com.example.springbootrestfulwebservice.entity.User)" because "this.userService" is null at com.example.springbootrestfulwebservice.controller.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:22) at Java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import com.example.springbootrestfulwebservice.entity.User;
import com.example.springbootrestfulwebservice.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("api/users")
public class UserController {

private UserService userService;

// build create User REST API
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user){
    User savedUser = userService.createUser(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(savedUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

// build get user by id REST API
// http://localhost:8080/api/users/1
@GetMapping("{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long userId){
    User user = userService.getUserById(userId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}

// Build Get All Users REST API
// http://localhost:8080/api/users
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers(){
    List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}

// Build Update User REST API
@PutMapping("{id}")
// http://localhost:8080/api/users/1
public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") Long userId,
                                       @RequestBody User user){
    user.setId(userId);
    User updatedUser = userService.updateUser(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
}

// Build Delete User REST API
@DeleteMapping("{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Long userId){
    userService.deleteUser(userId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("User successfully deleted!", HttpStatus.OK);
}

}


import com.example.springbootrestfulwebservice.entity.User;
import java.util.List;

public interface UserService {

User createUser(User user);

User getUserById(Long userId);

List<User> getAllUsers();

User updateUser(User user);

void deleteUser(Long userId);
}


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import com.example.springbootrestfulwebservice.entity.User;
import com.example.springbootrestfulwebservice.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.springbootrestfulwebservice.service.UserService;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Strings;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public User createUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}

@Override
public User getUserById(Long userId) {
    Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(userId);
    return optionalUser.get();
}

@Override
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public User updateUser(User user) {
    User existingUser = userRepository.findById(user.getId()).get();
    existingUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
    existingUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
    existingUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    User updatedUser = userRepository.save(existingUser);
    return updatedUser;
}

@Override
public void deleteUser(Long userId) {
    userRepository.deleteById(userId);
}
}
```

Comment: Read the stack trace: "because "this.userService" is null".  You didn't inject the user service into the REST controller properly.

Comment: How to inject the user service in the REST Controller. Im a beginner to Spring boot

Comment: Lombok is not the way to go.  My preference would be to use constructor injection: public UserController(UserService userService) {...}

Answer (score 1):

which version of spring boot do you use? If you're using old version of spring, then you need to create the constructor and add `@Autowired` above the constructor instead of using lombok annotation. Or you can change the lombok annotations like `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)`. Or just remove the lombok annoation and add `@Autowired` above `userService`.

Also make sure `userService` is a Spring Bean, check the annotation in `UserService`, it should have `@Service` or `@Component` or if it's created by `@Bean` method.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have an implementation of UserService marked as @Service.
if you have it, then save all files and re-run the application.

Answer (score -1):

You have to write '@AutoWired' above userService or make constructor with userService param